# Use database on Swift playgrounds (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, database, ipad, swift-playground

Is there any way to connect some of my iOS Playgrounds to Firebase or any other database?
I have really enjoyed Swift Playgrounds, I have playgrounds with more than 2 thousand of lines fetching json, html, web images and txt files and I use uikit and SceneKit.
So I want to see if there is any way to connect my playgrounds to a online database, because with that I can do better apps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Xcode project and import `Firebase` framework with [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org). Build & Run just to make sure the pod works.

After installation, open the `.xcworkspace` and add a new playground to the workspace & `import Firebase`.

You'll have access to all of the framework right in your playground.

Comment: I mean on iPad App of Swift Playgrounds

Comment: Ah.. Not possible. Playground for iPads are only limited to playground books & pages and can only use the Swift Standard Library.  No external frameworks.